# Anybody can help to reach exact path

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy.HH-mm-ss");

 var file = File.Create("myfile.txt" + timestamp);

 var dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) +
 DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") + @"\Owe-Data";

 if (!Directory.Exists(dir))

 {

         Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

 }
 using (var sw = new StreamWriter(dir + file))
 {
     sw.WriteLine(InputData);
 }

}
```

but when running the program it gives error

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder' does not contain a definition for 'CommonApplicationData'
```

maybe this folder not exist for windows phone can anybody suggest how to get path for windows phone

```
developing for windows phone, using visual studio 2008 .net framework 2.0
```

Comment: Don't re-post your question, instead update it with the relevant information.

Comment: @crashmstr: ok next time i'll care of it

Comment: problem solved by using
var com = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") + @"\Owe-Data";

instead of
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)

it does not have any folder in windows mobile

Comment: @user3012548 post your solution as an answer so this question has an answer